# Infinite For Loop - Javascript - Whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
function sortArray(array) {
    var tempArray = [];
    var tempNum;
    var tempPos;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i+= 1) {

        if (i = 0) {
            tempNum = parseInt(array[i]);
            tempPos = 0;
        }

        else if (parseInt(array[i]) <= tempNum) {
            tempNum = parseInt(array[i]);
            tempPos = i;
        }
    console.log(i);
    }

}
```

It's supposed to take an array and order it from least to greatest but didn't even get that far as the for loop becomes infinite. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code that's calling `sortArray`?

Comment: already answered. There was a mistake in the first if statement. i was setting i = 0 instead of comparing it with i == 0

Answer (score 5):

You're setting `i = 0` in the first if, which means you will never have i large enough to exit the for loop. You want to use `==` instead

ie:

```
if (i = 0) {
    tempNum = parseInt(array[i]);
    tempPos = 0;
}
```

should be

```
if (i == 0) {
    tempNum = parseInt(array[i]);
    tempPos = 0;
}
```